# User-filtered search in django

Tags: mysql, django, search

I'm brainstorming a search function for the user that is similar to iTunes Smart Playlists.  I can currently display all of the release years for all of the films in the database.  A user can pick a year and see all of the films released in that year.  Or I can show all of the genres of movie.  A user can choose a genre and see all of the movies that match that criteria.

What I want is a form that the user can dynamically choose their own criteria.  So for instance "Release Date" "is after" "2000" AND "Genre" "is not" "Horror" would return a filtered list.  All of these choices would be user supplied within a form that has dropdown choices.

It seems simple from a SQL point of view, but I'm wondering what the best implementation would be from to go from a django form to MySQL.  Any suggestions on a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build dictionaries from your form elements.

```
incdict = {'releasedate__gte': datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)}
excdict = {'genre': 'Horror'}
moviequery = Movie.objects.filter(**incdict).exclude(**excdict)
```