# Escape dangerous code when allowing user MySQL filter creation

Tags: jquery, mysql, django, json, filter

I can currently display all of the release years for all of the films in the database. A user can pick a year and see all of the films released in that year. Or I can show all of the genres of movie. A user can choose a genre and see all of the movies that match that criteria.  I built a form in which the user can dynamically choose their own criteria. So for instance "Release Date" "is after" "2000" would return a filtered list.

I wrote some UNPROTECTED jquery/django code to pass filters to the database.  Through a combination of drop down boxes and user input boxes (exactly like you would see in iTunes), I am using jquery to construct the filter.

As an example, let's say the user selects in the first drop down: "Year".  For the second drop down: "is".  The last is an input box where the user enters "2005."  This criteria is put into an array:

```
dictionary: 
[ 
   {"includes": [["year__iexact", "2005"]], 
    "excludes": []}, 
    "all" 
]
```

"includes"/"excludes" separates the criteria like "is", "is before" from things like "is not"
"all" designates that the filter should "match all", not "match any"

This is converted to JSON:

```
[{"includes":[["year__iexact","2005"]],"excludes":[]},"all"]
```

and posted to django.

The view in django then puts the data into the filter:

```
incdict[ filter[0].encode('utf-8') ] = filter[1].encode('utf-8')
```

This becomes:

```
incdict[ 'year__iexact' ] = 2005
```

That is fed into the query (as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161371/user-filtered-search-in-django):

```
query_set = Film.objects.filter(**incdict)
```

Ok, I hope that was clear.  What I ask now is how to protect against the unscrupulous user who seeks to bypass/exploit the input.  Do I need to escape special characters?  Data validation?  What is the best way to protect the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you allow fully freeform data into `filter()` and `exclude()`, there's no way to craft a dangerous query from them; the type of query is determined by the methods called, not the data passed.

Comment: Not related to the question but equally important thing to be careful about is to ensure that you do not include any sensitive data(user's private data for example) in your JS files.

Answer (score 3):

I would validate the input, and you will have to do that server side.

Maybe if you split your conditions on "__" (e.g. giving ["year", "iexact"]), you could compare those values against a whitelist. That way you can be sure that only your predefined of allowed queries will be executed.

Comment: I should be ok on this front.  The "year" and "iexact" portions are supplied only through drop down menus.  It's only the actual text box/user input that allows any manual filter criteria

Comment: I suppose this is a moot point in this context - since Ignacio points out that security is not an issue here - but you can't rely on *anything* client side. With a tool such as Firebug, a user can change the values of your drop down menus in a couple of clicks.

Comment: Excellent point and something I didn't realize.  I will keep an eye out for this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Even though users can't execute any obvious evil queries (deleting or getting secret data), you may have to worry about someone hitting your database often with complex queries (think multiple joins and some regexes or other selects on non-indexed columns) and these can take a long time to answer.

It also depends on the size of your database how many complex queries it can handle at one time, but this might make your site slower.

Comment: Noted.  I'm not sure how to counteract this.  I limit the number of filters to 6 to avoid this type of behavior.  I guess I'll just have to make adjustments depending on what I see.